# performance degradation with large pages

Tags: linux, memory-management, jvm, benchmarking, huge-pages

I play with a Java benchmark (SPECJbb) but observed some performance degradation with large pages (2M per page) enabled. Our server is `NUMA` arch based, has 80 cores (160 logical cpu when HT enabled) and `260G` memory.

The benchmark consumes about `200G` memory, so I allocated 200G large in kernel large page pool.But the performance is `6%~8%` decline. I think I should have some performance gain because this benchmark used 200G memory.

My question is about, in what situation, using large page will degrade performace?
Our OS is `RHEL6.3` and I tried H`otSpot JDK 1.6.38` and `1.6.37`, both these two versions I found such degradation. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Large pages should usually bring up to 5% performance improvement.

You should check whether the large pages were properly allocated:

- see `cat /proc/meminfo` and check for actual large pages allocation size
- How big is your Heap? Did you use the `-XX:+UseLargePages` option? See that the JVM managed to use large pages, there will be a warning in the JVM output log if there was any problem

Also, there could be a problem with LargePages + NUMA architecture. How much memory there is for each core? See:

- [Using Large Pages](http://linux-hacks.blogspot.com/2009/06/using-large-pages.html), they report about large pages performance degradation of 6-8% due NUMA 
  setting.
- [Huge Pages and NUMA issues on Linux](http://blogs.amd.com/developer/2009/01/23/huge-pages-and-numa-issues-on-linux/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I also checked this page http://linux-hacks.blogspot.com/2009/06/using-large-pages.html. The author said that "After some debugging, the issue turned out to be that the application was not able to utilize the large pages allocated (thanks to some weird environment I had ;-) ).". It seems that I have the same symptom with him, but he didn't describle the real reason in the blog.

Comment: Yes, thats the link I was referring to. Does your JVM manages to start with the huge pages you give it? What are your JVM options? And, are there any error messages? `HugePages_Free` number should decrease by the size of your heap.

Comment: Hi, I fixed this problem by running my benchmark using root. It seems that JVM uses SYS5 style api to allocate huge pages pool, which require root permission.

Comment: Nice! Good to know that it works for your OS at least for the root. Now you should be able to figure out howto run under other users - because I know that it should work as well.